# Unable to scroll after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fetch data from `json` file and then attach the data as `listitem` in a unordered list.

So its getting listed successfully, but I cannot scroll again through it.

Here is how my Javascript looks like:

```
function ListViewData(allpost) {
    allposts = allpost;
    $.each(allpost.posts, function (i, row) {
        if (row.thumbnail_images) {
            $(".list__container").append('<li class="list__item list__item--tappable list__item__line-height list-item-container">' +
                '<div class="list-item-main">' +
                '<div class="list-item-left">' +
                '<img src="' + row.thumbnail_images['full'].url + '" class="thumbnail" width="80" height="80">' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="list-item-right">' +
                '<div class="list-item-content">' +
                '<span class="list-item-name">' + row.title + ' &nbsp; ' +
                '<br/>' +
                '<span class="lucent">' +
                '<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>&nbsp; Paris, France' +
                '</span>' +
                '</span>' +
                '<br/>' +
                '<span class="list-item-text" style="margin-top:16px;">Eiffel Tower is the symbol of Paris and named by Gustave Eiffel.' +
                '</span>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<span class="list-item-action" >' +
                '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>' +
                '</span>' +
                '</li>');
        }
        $(".list__container").listview();
    });
    $('.list__container').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.list__container').prop("scrollHeight")
    }, 500);
}
```

and here is how my HTML code looks like:

```
<div class="list list-top">
<ul class="list__container">
 //here append data comes in place   
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('.list__container').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.list__container').prop("scrollHeight")
}, 500);
```

Try

```
$("html,body").animate({
    scrollTop: $('.list__container').prop("scrollHeight")
}, 500);
```

Comment: Is slides down to bottom, and then i can not scroll through.

Comment: I have a css attached to the main body,  where overflow is hidden. So is there any another way i can fix this?